# React-Native: how to update a components value (and display the updated value) when a separate component's value changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

In the code below, for React-Native, I would like the the NumericInput for 'count' to update and be displayed when the number of 'containers' changes. The input for 'count' must be able to be modified by user input as well as be the result of the calculation in the onChange function from 'containers'.

How can I do this in React-Native?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NumericInput from 'react-native-numeric-input';

const Plot = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [countainers, setContainers] = useState(0);

    return (
        <View>
            {/* input for number of containers ... each container has 10 items */}
            <NumericInput
                value={countainers}
                onChange={c => { setContainers(c); setCount(containers * 10); }}
            />
            {/* input for total count of items */}
            <NumericInput
                onChange={c => setCount(c)}
                value={count}
            />
        </View>
    );
}

export default Plot;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the 'react-native-numeric-input' api is broken for the version and dependency versions I have. The code that was posted should have worked just fine as-is but just didn't. Changing it to any other component (and I chose a simple TextInput that allows 0-9 only) proved this to be the case.